# How can I throw different kind of excptions in one method

Tags: java, exception, throw

I just started learning Java, and I am stuck. I was told to handle a call to a method, in the main method that can throw different types of exceptions.

What is thrown: `IOException`
How to handle: Wrap in an IllegalArgumentException with a message "Resource error" and throw it

What is thrown: `FileNotFoundException`
How to handle: Wrap in an IllegalArgumentException with a message "Resource is missing" and throw it:

This is a starting point, that is given:

```java
static Exception exception = new FileNotFoundException();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  riskyMethod();
}

public static void riskyMethod() throws Exception {
  throw exception;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

To handle the exceptions `riskyMethod()` can throw, put it into a `try-catch` block. You can put several `catch` blocks after `try` to handle different exceptions. To wrap any exception into an `IllegalArgumentException` pass the exception as the second argument to the constructor. The first argument is the error string.
The whole code:

```
static Exception exception = new FileNotFoundException();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try{
        riskyMethod();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Resource is missing", e);
    }catch(IOException e){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Resource error", e);
    }
}

public static void riskyMethod() throws Exception {
   throw exception;
}
```

I did not test this code, but after adding the necessary imports it should work.

Comment: What does this answer add exactly? Isn't it better to just throw the original exception?

Answer (score 0):

First, remove `throws Exception` from your `main`.

Handling an exception means not re-throwing it, or throwing a different one.

Catch the exception and do something with it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        riskyMethod();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

You can print what you like - this is just a suggestion.

Note that you don't need to specifically catch `FileNotFoundException`, because it is an `IOException`.